# Could not find stored procedure ' '. SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have created a stored procedure and am receiving the following error when trying to call it using an exec 'procedure_name' statement. The procedure has a chunk of static SQL code in the first half and then dynamic code for the last half...

```
calcNums(Param1, Param2, etc...)
--------
DECLARE a bunch of variables
--------

STATIC CODE here

-------
SET @SQL = DYNAMIC CODE

EXEC @SQL
```

I have the right database connection selected and I created the procedure with the dbo. schema prefix.

If I call the procedure without any parameters then I get an error of...

> Procedure or function 'calcNums' expects parameter 'Param1' which was not supplied.

Otherwise it gives me the error...

```
Could not find stored procedure ' '.
```

Can anyone give me an idea as to why I am getting this error?

Comment: is that your actual code ? I can't reproduce what you are asking. Too vague

Comment: Have you tried to debug this by printing out the value of @SQL by adding the statement `PRINT @SQL` or `SELECT @SQL`? It sounds like the value of @SQL might not be what you expected.

Comment: @Adam while possible, the current syntax being used `EXEC @sql;` vs `EXEC(@sql);` will still not work, regardless of what string is in `@sql`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I was able to get `EXEC @sql` to work when the value of `@sql` was set to the stored procedure name without parameters. For example: `set @sql = 'sp_help'.  Here's an example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fe251/1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make sure `@sql` is `NVARCHAR`.
2. You can't say `EXEC @sql`. You should use:

   ```
   EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
   ```

   If `@sql` is just a procedure name, then being more explicit is probably better:

   ```
   SET @sql = N'EXEC ' + @sql;
   EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
   ```

   The lazy workaround is to use the following, [but I think the above is better](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql), especially if some of your parameters can bas passed in explicitly:

   ```
   EXEC(@sql);
   ```